# Where is The Value of the Current Stack Pointer Register Stored Before Context Switching In POSIX C Threads

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, context-switch, stack-pointer

If I were to use pthreads in POSIX environments, and a context switch is about to happen, the current value of the `esp` register has to be stored somewhere so I can retrieve it when I context switch back to this thread, as the `esp` register's value will be overwritten by another thread's saved SP value. I think it is impossible to have separate `esp` register for every thread (correct me if I am wrong). Having said that, I would like to know in what data structure the SP value of the current thread is stored right before the context switching is hit?

I tried looking up the `struct pthread*`'s value casted from the value of `pthread_t`, but nothing was changing when, say, I call a certain function to change the current SP of the thread I am testing (i.e. compare before and after calling the testing function).

Comment: I'd think that a user-level threading library would rely on OS for context switching., i.e., `pthread_yield()` calls `sched_yield()`. This information (`sp`) is available inside the [task struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h).

Comment: @Arash Is it a kernel level struct??

Comment: Yes. it is.....

Comment: As stated above, the kernel handles that on Linux, and on most other OS:es that have pthreads as well.

Comment: In linux (many others as well), these are built on top of the [clone](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscall, which you can specify the memory for the "thread's" stack for (either on the heap or the stack or some other strange way if you want)  Best way to know is to look at the source for your libc or [musl-libc's thread code](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely upon how the Posix library is implemented. If the threads are implemented by the OS, the values of all registers are stored in the thread's [process] context block before a context switch.

if the thread are implemented in a library, the registers have to be stored in some data structure managed by the library. Such a library implementation needs to save all the general registers but does not (and cannot) need to save the process-specific kernel registers.